# When I pass data from TableView to child PageViewController, it can go to next child

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, xcode7, uipageviewcontroller

I have an `UIViewController` with a `UITableView`. Then I create a `PageViewController` with two `viewcontroller`. `Pageview` doesn't work if I pass data to child. If I change

```
setViewControllers([subjective], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

to

```
setViewControllers([firstVC], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Pageview work but data don't pass. I don't have any idea about it. Help me please. Thanks

**Code Work:**

**pageview controller class**:

```
import UIKit

class PageVC : UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

var lblhoten = String()
var lblngaysinh = String()
var lblsodt = String()

lazy var VCArr: [UIViewController] = {
    return [self.VCInstance("ThongTinBNPage2"),
            self.VCInstance("ThongTinBNPage3")]
}()

private func VCInstance(name: String) -> UIViewController {
    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(name)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self
    if let firstVC = VCArr.first {
        let subjective = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ThongTinBNPage2") as! VCSubjective
        subjective.lblhoten = lblhoten
        subjective.lblngaysinh = lblngaysinh
        subjective.lblsodt = lblsodt
        setViewControllers([subjective], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

public func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewcontrollerindex = VCArr.indexOf(viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let previousindex = viewcontrollerindex - 1


    guard previousindex >= 0 else {
        return VCArr.last
    }

    guard VCArr.count > previousindex else {
        return nil
    }

    return VCArr[previousindex]
}

public func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewcontrollerindex = VCArr.indexOf(viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let nextindex = viewcontrollerindex + 1


    guard nextindex < VCArr.count else {
        return VCArr.first
    }

    guard VCArr.count > nextindex else {
        return nil
    }

    return VCArr[nextindex]
}

public func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return VCArr.count
}

// The selected item reflected in the page indicator.
public func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    guard let firstviewcontroller = viewControllers?.first,
        let firstviewcontrollerindex = VCArr.indexOf(firstviewcontroller) else {
            return 0
    }

    return firstviewcontrollerindex
}
```

}

**VCSubjective:**

```
import UIKit

class VCSubjective: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var hoten: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var ngaysinh: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var sodt: UILabel!

var lblhoten = String()
var lblngaysinh = String()
var lblsodt = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.        
    hoten.text = lblhoten
    ngaysinh.text = lblngaysinh
    sodt.text = lblsodt
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: Why I have two downvotes here? Please comment at least one reason to downvote anyone!!!

Comment: Two users have voted to close this question as it is "unclear what you are asking". Maybe rephrase your question. What is the actual issue and what is your question. Avoid terms like "doesn't work" for obvious reasons. You can [edit your question here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41774975/edit).

Comment: Sry about this. But I think I tried my best to present.

Comment: Page view controllers are container view controllers.  Where are your content view controllers?

Comment: edited for VCSubjective ( ViewController child of page view, which I wanna pass data to)

Comment: Give me your project

Comment: I sent you my project. Can you help me one more problem with search controller. I will give you the link!?

Comment: @ThinhLe Can you give me your project? I have implemented this in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are referencing two completely different objects.

In `viewDidLoad` you create `ThongTinBNPage2` viewController and then add it to the viewControllers property of the pageViewController. However, the objects stored in VCArr are two totally different viewControllers.

Let's think about it this way:

1. When `viewDidLoad` is called you create viewController `object #1`
2. Then you assign the viewController `object #1` to the viewControllers object of the pageViewController making the value of `viewControllers = [object #1]`
3. In `pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?` and `pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?` you reference the VCArr object. On the first call to VCArr, it lazily creates two completely different view controller objects `[object #2, object #3]`

To fix this code you need to do the following:

```
if let firstVC = VCArr.first {
    let subjective = firstVC   // DO NOT create different VC here
    subjective.lblhoten = lblhoten
    subjective.lblngaysinh = lblngaysinh
    subjective.lblsodt = lblsodt
    setViewControllers([subjective], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks you. I updated to xcode 8 and swift 3 then it done.